# Is it possible for mannequins to retain their armour when I quit my game?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I got some mannequins using the console command. They don't have the interaction feature that allows you to use the mannequin and equip it with armor.

So I tried something clever. I used the console command to equip the mannequins instead by clicking on it and simply equipping it with the armor of choice. And it worked.

But the next day I went to play Skyrim, the mannequins were completely nude again. How do I keep the armor on the mannequins I got through the console command?

Comment: Short awnser, you can't

Comment: Mannequins are a complicated mess. You can't just console them into the game and expect them to behave correctly. You either need to use a house mod or a vanilla house that already has mannequins. Also, as a rule of thumb: Never, never, *never* try to "fix" a mannequin with the console. If you `disable`/`enable` them, it will just make things worse.